# How do I catch non-regular characters in regal regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to catch this block of text using regal regular expression:

> ¡¾Ìá¡¿#/¡¾¹©¡¿/¸÷/ÐÐ/Òµ/¡¾°l¡¿*/¡¾Æ±¡¿¡£
>   µç»°13534018113ÕÅÉú
>   ¾´Çë±£Áô•½±ãÁªÏµ

I used `[^a-zA-Z]+` which I expect should cover new line character and white spaces.
This is not the case. I don't know why. Is there a special character that is covered by a-z or A-Z?

Comment: Your language? Add a tag please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the single line modifier with whatever language you're using. Add a tag next time.

Here's a working regular expression for PCRE: `/[^a-z]+/gis`

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/pA4dG2